# Patterns for passing args to _binary rules in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a macro `go_server` that calls `go_binary` among others. Here's an example of it being used:

```
go_server(
    name = "service",
    library = ":go_default_library",  # go_binary
    args = [
        "--respPrefix", "OH HAI",
        "--port", "4040",
    ],
)
```

Questions:

- the `args` above has an error: `OH HAI` should be escaped otherwise it gets passed to the shell as two separate arguments. I found that `"'OH HAI'"` works, but is there a better way - say, a function like `strings.shell_escape("OH HAI")` or so?
- could you point me to an example open-source code instantiation of a bazel rule that has complex args? I'm looking for patterns related to dictionaries, string escaping etc. Or should I use something like `jsonnet` for managing my args instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to escape. To keep the string identical, it would be

```
"--respPrefix", "\"OH HAI\"",
```